# Solving $ \theta \sin \theta=2\pi \varphi, $ for $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to solve $\theta$ from the following equation
$$
\theta \sin \theta=2\pi \varphi,
$$
where $\varphi$ can be any element of $[0,1]$. I know that there are infinite solutions for $\theta$. Define the smallest solution as $\theta_m=\min\{\theta|\theta \sin \theta=2\pi \varphi\}$. What I wonder is whether we can obtain the analytic expression of $\theta_m$, i.e., $\theta_m=f(\varphi)$.

Thanks a lot~

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Pendronator My attempt is to solve the equation using some numerical methods, e.g., Newton method. Can you offer me some valuable advice?

Comment: Try writing a Python script or graphing it and see if you can deduce any patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a transcendental equation which will not show any anytical solution even using special function. This means that you need some numerical method.

However, we can make some approximation limiting the problem to $0 \leq \varphi\leq \frac 12$.

For conveniency, i shall rewrite the equation as
$$x \sin(x)=k$$

If you accept it, the problem could have been solved $1,400$ years ago since the approximation

$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$ was proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician.

This leads to the problem of solving the cubic
$$5 \pi ^2 k-4 \pi  k x-4(4\pi-k ) x^2+16 x^3=0$$

Trying for $k=1$, the *approximate* solutions are $1.11495$ and $2.77389$ while the "exact" solutions, obtained using Newton method, are $1.11416$ and $2.77260$. Not too bad, isn't it ?

For $\frac 12 \leq \varphi\leq 1$, make $x =y+\pi$ and using the same approximation, solve, using Cardano method again, the cubic
$$-5 \pi ^2 k-4\pi\left(4 \pi-  k\right) y-4 k y^2+16   y^3=0$$